# Slow Cheetah 2.5.14 doesn't work on TeamCity

Tags: nuget, teamcity, slowcheetah

When I installed Slow Cheetah 2.5.14 and try to build package in TeamCity doesn't work.

I get the below error "Cannot add part to the package. Part names cannot be derived from another part name by appending segments to it.
Process exited with code 1"

Things I noticed when I have installed 2.5.14 the version on the SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets is not matching with the version I installed it says

`<sc-MSBuildLibPathLocal Condition=" '$(sc-MSBuildLibPathLocal)'=='' ">$(LocalAppData)\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.11\</sc-MSBuildLibPathLocal>` and the same can be seen in the targets file at different locations. I'm not sure why I can't build the package in TeamCity. I have followed different posts but didnt had any luck.

Comment: Does the project have the SlowCheetah nuget pkg installed? It sounds like the pkg may not have been installed into the project.

Comment: Sayed, I have installed the SlowCheetah nuget pack on the project I'm building and also used package restore step in Teamcity to download other nuget packages that are used in my project.